# Probability and the Complement Rule

Tags: probability

If the probability of selecting A is 20% and B is 80%, what is the probability that the next three to be selected is A?

> P (next three is A) = (0.2) (0.2) (0.2) = 0.008.
>
> However, using the complement rule: P (next three is A) = 1 - [ P (next three is B) ] = 1 - [(0.8)(0.8)(0.8)] = 0.488.

Why does the two computations give different answers? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

The complement of "the next three is A" is not "the next three is B", but rather "the next three is AAB, ABA, ABB, BAA, BAB, BBA, or BBB", and you would have to calculate the probability of each of those, add them together, and subtract it from 1 to compute P("the next three is A") using the complement method. (You're better off just computing it directly. ;))

Comment: I see. However, plugging the answer using computation 1 does not yield a correct answer in an automated math exam. That means computation 1 is incorrect. But mention was not made whether the events are independent.

Comment: 0.008 was the wrong answer? I'm not sure why that would be. Where is the question from?

Comment: @Florencio The computation is *numerically* correct, however the automated exam may be finicky on *format* and require: $0.8\%$, or something.

Comment: It requires answers to be written in 3 decimal places, and it was marked incorrect. I am really doubtful about university online-graded quizzes.

Comment: The quiz having been set with the wrong answer is also a possibility.